# Writing something(using touch) on the screen and saving it in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am building an application in blackberry in which I have to allow user write something (by touch) on the screen (for example save signature of the user ) and have show it some where else or in some other page.

Please tell me whether **it is feasible or not**  in blackberry.
If yes then please give some link or code to perform this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it personally, but I see no reason why it wouldn't be feasible. You would need to override `protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message)` and store the coordinates of the touch from the DOWN event to the UP event. There is actually a method `TouchEvent.getMovePoints(int, int[], int[], int[])` that should make tracking the path fairly straightforward.

So after you get the touch events you can use `Graphics.drawOutlinedPath(int[], int[], byte[], int[], boolean)` to draw the path where you need it displayed.

Comment: No problem! Just add a comment with any other questions and I'll add it to the answer if I can actually answer it.

Comment: Thanks jprofitt for the support. One thing I have posted one more question regarding the **generation of PDF in blackberry**. But i didnt have any reply  yet. So please check if you have any idea on that topic too.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I don't know anything about creating PDFs on the BB.